# Saving the Users Game Scores on iOS

Tags: ios, plist

I am developing an iOS game and I have two questions. First, I am maintaining the levels information (scores, background image, etc) into a plist file. The first time that the app is launched, I copy the plist file from the resources directory to the documents directory (I need to write the user best scores into it). Exits a best way to maintaing this information? Second, if I make an update of the app, adding new levels par example, how can I add the update new information without losing the current user scores?

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. A property list seems as good a way to keep track of high scores and such as any other. If you've already got that working, stick with it until you have a good reason to change.
2. Your data file (indeed, the entire contents of the Documents directory) will be preserved when the user updates to a new version of the app.

Comment: Thanks for responding so quickly. About 1., I will follow your advice and I will continue using property lists files. About 2., If the data file will be preserved, I suppose that the only thing that I have to do when I will introduce new levels updating the app, is to copy the current user data into the new property list file and to change the user current property list file by the updated one. Is not it?

Comment: That sounds about right, but you may not even need to update the existing file. I'd suggest using different files: one for user info, like best score per level; one for things the user can't change, like the background image for each level. The file with immutable stuff can just stay in the app bundle. For the user info, you should have some reasonable default built into the app for data that doesn't exist. For example, if you have a dictionary of high scores for each level, you might find that you get back nil because there is no value. In that case, just assume the score is 0 for that level.

Answer (score 1):

AS Caleb said, a pList file is probably fine for saving high scores.

I'd like to add a bit about #2.  You can just always re-use the same save file for simplicity, as long as you plan ahead for updates.  This is a lot easier than trying to juggle different plist files for different versions.

When you create your game save plist file, just be sure to include a field for a save game format version number.  That way, for future releases, you can open the save file, read the version number, and make any necessary adjustments to bring it up to the current version.  This is extremely handy when players can essentially skip updates, downloading version 1 and 3 but skipping 2.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Caleb. It's best to have a little source code to help you.

I created [this sample code](https://github.com/faizanaziz/HighScore) that has both local and global support.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to have a look at the [NSUserDefaults](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html) class which provides basic management capabilities for storing app data. For more advanced data storage, [CoreData](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/cdProgrammingGuide.html) is the recommended way to go.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I think that I will keep using property list files. Currently, I have a lot of code working and using plist files. About CoreData, I do not need a data base. I do not have enough data volume.

Comment: Core Data does not necessarily mean you need to have high data volume or database. It's probably more the complexity of the data that makes the difference - it's usually easier to work with Core Data when you have complex relationships between your entities.

Comment: I know, but in my case I do not have complex relationships. I know about Core Data, but, in this case, I prefer lighter solution. Thank you anyway.